# CodeIgniter: undefined function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I get this error when I try to run my code, I'm just trying to test it out and I got this error, I'm trying to create a account registration and I'm required to use `Codeigniter` and I saw a similar code in the net and I try to follow it but somehow I got error with this and I don't know what I'm missing sorry I'm new to `Codeigniter`

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_project\application\views\welcome_message.php on line 9
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function form_open()
>
> Filename: views/welcome_message.php
>
> Line Number: 9
>
> Backtrace:

Here is my code for view

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Create Account</title>
    </head>
        <body>
          <h3>Create Account</h3>
          <?php
                echo form_open(CreateAccount_Controller,submit_data);

                echo form_label('User Name:', 'Vu_name' );
                $data= array(
                'name' => 'u_name',
                'placeholder' => 'Please Enter User Name',
                'class' => 'input_box'
                );
                echo form_input($data);
                ?>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Here is my code for controller

```
     <?php
       class CreateAccount_Controller extends CI_Controller
       {
           public function _construct ()
           {
              parent::_construct();
           }
           public function create_account ()
           {
              $this->load->view(CreateAccount_View);
           }
              public function submit_data ()
           {
              // return hi or something;
           }
       }
     ?>
```

Comment: `$this->load->helper('form');`  ?

Comment: Hello, where do I add that?

Comment: you need to load the **helper form** in `autoload.php` or as @splash58 in the controller in the method or in constructor

Comment: after complete all form inputs/data you need to close the form aslo <?php echo form_close(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the helper in your controller constructor and Your code will be as follows:

```
<?php
       class CreateAccount_Controller extends CI_Controller
       {
           public function _construct ()
           {
              parent::_construct();
              $this->load->helper('form');
           }
           public function create_account ()
           {
              $this->load->view(CreateAccount_View);
           }
              public function submit_data ()
           {
              // return hi or something;
           }
       }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to load form helpers in your code.

Please load the helper in `autoload.php` under `application/config`

`$autoload['helper'] = array('helper');`

OR

Load the helper in your controller constructor.

```
<?php
       class CreateAccount_Controller extends CI_Controller
       {
           public function _construct ()
           {
              parent::_construct();
              $this->load->helper('form');
           }
           public function create_account ()
           {
              $this->load->view(CreateAccount_View);
           }
              public function submit_data ()
           {
              // return hi or something;
           }
       }
     ?>
```

Hope this helps you.